# App is causing iOS to ask constantly user to change location permission - iOS13

Tags: permissions, background, location, ios13

I am facing an issue of frequent location tracking reminders even user has chosen "`Changes to Always Allow`" option from second permission dialogue which generally appears after some time when App tries to retrieve location in the background.
As per my understanding, this is a periodic reminder to the user that App is using location in background and they still want to keep change and degrade the permission.
Ideally, it comes in the frequency of 3, 7, 14 days like so. this is my observation for other apps which monitor location in the background with "`Always Allow`" permission
But in my case, This tracking reminders come 4-5 times in a day on 3rd Day.

I am using multiple `CLLocationManager` in code and this should not be an issue.
Also, I am calling `requestAlwaysAuthorization()` method with a pre check that if the user has not granted "Always Allow". As per documentation if `**authorizationStatus != kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined**`, then this method will do nothing. So calling this method multiple time should not be an issue.

`pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` is `false` and `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates` is `true` in code.

So what could be a reason of it? Or is it depends on iOS and no control of the developer?

[image]